# How to change color of data points to match treatment groups?

Tags: r, pca, rgl

I am currently using RStudio to generate a 3D plot for my PCA using data imported from SPSS.

Currently, I have 10 treatment groups, each with 5 subjects. I would like to plot a 3d plot where each treatment group is represented by a color, and each subject in the same treatment group has the same color.
It is also vital that none of these colors are repeated.

I am able to generate the 3d plot however, there are 2 treatment groups that utilizes the same color.

Can anyone help me rectify this issue so there would be no repeating colors for different treatment groups?

Here's the code that I'm using.

```
db = file.choose()

hpca = read.table(db, header=TRUE)

pc <- princomp(hpca[,2:7], cor=TRUE, scores=TRUE)


 plot3d(pc$scores[,1:3], col=hpca$group, size = 6)
 text3d(pc$scores[,1:3],texts=hpca$ï..tag)
 text3d(pc$loadings[,1:3], texts=rownames(pc$loadings), col="red")
 coords <- NULL
 for (i in 1:nrow(pc$loadings)) {
     coords <- rbind(coords, rbind(c(0,0,0),pc$loadings[i,1:3]))
 }
 lines3d(coords, col="red", lwd=4)
```

*p/s; I am completely new to R programming and most of these codes are copied from an online guide. Therefore it would be extremely helpful if you could show me where exactly to include the changes. 
Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the colour to be the group value.  That sometimes works, because group values are usually factors and factors are stored as integer values, but it is kind of hit and miss.

It is better to compute the colour explicitly.  For example, you can get a vector of 10 colours using

```
cols <- rainbow(10)
```

and then use it as

```
plot3d(..., col=cols[as.numeric(gp)])
```

if `gp` contains a factor with 10 levels.

There are several functions in base R to select colours (see `?rainbow`) and others in contributed packages for different palettes.